# Как стать разработчиком битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день, друзья! У меня к вам такой вопрос, как стать разработчиком битрикс? Все кто работали с битриксом знают, что существует демо-версия пользования системой и коммерческая. Демо-версия предоставляется на 30 дней (скачивается виртуальная машина и работаешь с ней). Но так как за 30 дней систему толком нельзя выучить, с учетом малого свободного времени, чтобы посвящать себя досугу изучения битриксу. Возникает вопрос как стать разработчиком битрикс вне лимита 30 дней. На собеседовании одном на должность веб-программиста мне сказали, что можно зарегистрироваться на сайте битрикс и стать разработчиком, тогда все это бесплатно можно обучаться и ставить сайты сколько душе угодно. Так ли это? И как развернуть это на локальной машине и на определенном домене например в сети такую безлимитную систему пользования битриксом? Спасибо, за ответы, если они будут исчерпывающими и ясными.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы можете несколько раз переустанавливать демо-версию. Как только срок демо-лицензии истек - ставьте новую.

> Но так как за 30 дней систему толком
> нельзя выучить, с учетом малого
> свободного времени, чтобы посвящать
> себя досугу изучения битриксу.

Попробуйте, установите :) вам хватит времени, чтобы разобраться как с ней работать в роли администратора, я вас уверяю. Кроме того есть прекрасные курсы Битрикс прямо у них на сайте. Изучайте!

Вам доступны:

- [техническая поддержка](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/) сотрудников «1С-Битрикс» по техническим вопросам разработки и настройки сайтов;
- [полная документация](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/docs/) по продуктам, включающая описание API Framework;
- [Учебные курсы](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/index.php) для разработчиков;
- [рекомендации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/docs/php.php#tab-integration-link) по конфигурированию серверов, разработке модулей и т.п.;
- [сообщество профессиональных разработчиков](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/), готовых посоветовать и проконсультировать по техническим вопросам.

Comment: Спасибо, большое за ответ! Значит стать разработчиком и пользоваться безлимитно битриксом нельзя. Это я и хотел услышать. Спасибо за информацию в наглядной форме.